# How to avoid automatically reading unread Thunderbird mails when changing folders?

Tags: email, thunderbird

Whenever I mark mails as unread in Thunderbird, and I change folders and come back to the folder, it automatically reads the mail I just marked as unread (thus marking it read). How do I avoid Thunderbird automatically reading mails whenever changing folders? As a context, I like to mark mails as unread to make sure they stay on top when sorting by unread, Thunderbird's behavior as described makes for some mails slipping through this method sometimes if I'm not careful.

EDIT: I'd still like my mails to be read when clicking on them (just not when changing folders). So unchecking "Automatically mark messages as read" won't do.

Answer (score 1):

In *Thunderbird* menu item *Settings*, search for *mark*. Either uncheck *Automatically mark messages as read*, or leave it checked, but set a delay for *After displaying for *n* seconds*.

[image: Mark Read after 1 second]

Comment: But with this, no mails get marked as read, unless manually marking them as read. Maybe I should've been more specific: I'd like my mails to be read when clicking on them, not when changing folders

Comment: Did you not see the delay can be as little as 1 second? Just pause for that time after clicking to mark it read.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I don't see how this solves my problem